# How do I create a data frame from columns of different data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to create a `dataframe` that contains the latitude and longitude from one table, and a sampling event from another table. The table containing latitude and longitude also contains the sampling event column (this table is called "filtered_data"). However the sampling event is repeated multiple times for other criteria so I cannot use it as it is.

I used the following code...

```r
unique_sample = data.frame(unique(filtered_data$SAMPLING.EVENT.IDENTIFIER))
```

... to extract unique values from the sampling event column and put them in a new `dataframe`.
From here I would like to join the lat/long info from the filtered_data column to the unique_sample df.

This last step is where I am stuck. I've tried the merge function but to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide some of your data via `dput(head(filtered_data))`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered an easier answer:

SUBSET = filtered_data %>%
distinct(SAMPLING.EVENT.IDENTIFIER, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE)

this code allows me to extract distinct/unique records of the sampling event from the original df that include the columns I want (lat/long) without the extra steps I listed above.

Cheers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).